# Order linq.js results numerically

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am trying to return a list of periods (weeks) in a resource planning tool. Currently I am returning the data and ordering, but linq.js orders alphabetically and returns 1, 11, 12, 3, ...

How can I amend the query so that is sorted numerically? 1, 2, 3 ...

```
var teamMembers = Enumerable
    .From(data)
    .SelectMany("$.persons")
    .SelectMany("$.periods")
    .Where("$.teamName == '" + teamName + "'")
    .OrderBy("$.periodName")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var teamMembers = Enumerable
    .From(data)
    .SelectMany("$.persons")
    .SelectMany("$.periods")
    .Where("$.teamName == '" + teamName + "'")
    .OrderBy(function (x) { return parseInt(x.periodName); })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var teamMembers = Enumerable
    .From(data)
    .SelectMany("$.persons")
    .SelectMany("$.periods")
    .Where("$.teamName == '" + teamName + "'")
    .OrderBy(function (x) { return x.periodName; })
```

You have to make sure you are ordering a number.